# How to read 10GB .csv file using c# windows application

Tags: c#

I am try to read 10GB .csv file and import in our db. but when i am read this file via data adapter to fill data set or data table its give out of memory exception.

Comment: Please show your work and stack trace as well. Put more details about your problem. Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @AlexH - A good question needs to be clear, show research effort, and be useful, is this all 3 of those things?

Comment: @Sayse I mean in a general point of view: when i begun programming i didn't know the different between reading a whole file or line by line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileHelpers throws OutOfMemoryException when parsing large csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233454/filehelpers-throws-outofmemoryexception-when-parsing-large-csv-file)

Comment: If you're importing a .csv file into a DB and if this is an one-time operation, why not use an existing tool? AFAIK, most of them read line-by-line instead of loading it all in memory like you appear to be doing.

Comment: @AlexH - Aside from the missing effort in this question, you (and others) have assumed that the op is reading the whole file instead of line by line. That may be so but it isn't clear that that is the case. You are entitled to your opinion on this question, I just disagree

Comment: I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988195/how-do-i-read-a-large-file-from-disk-to-database-without-running-out-of-memory) here. Some of the answers, links and examples might prove to be useful to you.

Comment: Transferring 10GB data doesn't mean loading them one time. Is it possible to leverage existing tools?

Answer (score 2):

As per the MSDN documentation for the [`SqlDataAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

> Represents a set of data commands and a database connection that are
>   used to fill the DataSet and update a SQL Server database. This class
>   cannot be inherited.

If we where to look at the [`DataSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

> Represents an in-memory cache of data.

Thus this means that you need to have enough memory for the data set to be stored in it. The question does not provide detail on how is the file actually read, but for this to work you would need to essentially:

1. Iterate over the file 1 row at a time, do not load the entire file, say as a string in memory. You can use a [`TextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader(v=vs.110).aspx) to read.
2. You would then use an [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) to write into the database one line at a time.

This should allow you to essentially keep pointers to where the data is and where it needs to go, thus it reduces the amount of data you need to store in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You may read your file line by line and import to database. For parsing CSV use [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper).

Comment: Unreliable due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566052/can-you-encode-cr-lf-in-into-csv-files